# Compare textbox to sql database, insert sql command

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 to create a "project" for school. It is pretty simple.

The idea is for a patient self-check-in kiosk for a medical facility.

I already have my sql database created with the following:

```
Table: Doctors
Fields: Doctor_ID (PK), Doctor_F_Name, Doctor_L_Name

Table: Patients
Fields: Patient_ID (PK), Patient_F_Name, Patient_L_Name

Table: Appointments
Fields: Appointment_ID (PK), Appt_Day, Appt_Mo, Appt_Yr, Patient_ID (SK), Doctor_ID (SK), Appt_Time, Appt_Reason, Checked_In
```

So the first page of the code has a simple layout with 3 text entry boxes asking for the patients first name, last name, and last 4 of SSN (`Patient_ID`) and a submit button.

I would like for the data from the text boxes to be used to compare to the database and ask the question "are you here to check-in for your appointment today at (`Appt_Time`) with (Dr. `Doctor_L_Name`) for (`Appt_Reason`)?) and then a check box or drop down for yes or no, if yes is chosen then it inserts a "1" (`binary`) into checked_in field

I have gotten the text boxes and button created:

```
<script runat="server">
sub submit (sender as object, e as eventargs)
lbl1.text= "Hello, " & Textbox1.text &" " & Textbox2.Text
end sub
</script>

<h2> First Name </h2>
<asp:textbox id=Textbox1" runat"server" />
<h2> Last Name </h2>
<asp:textbox id=Textbox2" runat"server" />
<h2> Last 4 of SSN </h2>
<asp:textbox id=Textbox3" runat"server" />
<asp:button: ID="Button1" onclick="submit" runat="server" text="submit" />
<asp::label id="lbl1" runat="server" />
```

Below this I have a few debug checks to make sure communication with the sql server is working, and I can pull table information into a gridview without issue using the following connection settings:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="sqldatasource3" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ connectionstrings:PB_MedicalConnectionString %>"
selectcommand="select * from [Patients]" />
```

Then running a gridview:

```
<asp:gridview id="gridview1" runat="server" datakeyNames="Patient_ID" Datasource="sqldatasource3">
<columns>
<asp:boundfield datafield="Patient_ID" HeaderText="Patient_ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression=""Patient_ID" />
<asp:boundfield datafield="Patient_F_Name" HeaderText="Patient_F_Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression=""Patient_F_Name" />
<asp:boundfield datafield="Patient_L_Name" HeaderText="Patient_L_Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression=""Patient_L_Name" />
</columns>
<//asp:gridview>
```

This successfully returns the "patients" already entered into the database.

Any help creating/finishing this would be great. I am getting very tired of searching for tips, trying, failing searching, trying, failing.....

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Eric, congratulations on what you have done so far! Welcome to Stack Overflow. I here you saying: "Here is the code I have done, finish my school project for me". Though I can feel your frustration, there is an old saying: "Feed a man a fish and he will starve for 1,000 years, teach a man to fish and he will eat for 1,000 years". Please ask specific questions about your problem as we cant "finish your classwork" for you. Programming is : "trying, failing searching, trying, failing....."

Comment: The problem I am having is I dont know how to take the entered data and compare it to the table, taking the valid entry and returning to the web page, then completing the insert once the "yes" is chosen. I am guessing I need to write an if/then/else which I have done in python, I just dont know how to get that into asp so it is useable. Amd. for the record, this is not a homework assignment, its more of a self-assigned project and I wasnt looking for it to be completed, I am looking help, where to go next with the code, etc.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in logic... had to update it re-worded. Let me know if that kind of explains how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good advice:

Don't use direct in line SQL in an ASP page. Its always recommended, no longer how easy and simple the call, use a stored procedure in SQL and have the asp.net page call the stored procedure with the parameters. There is something evil out their called "SQL Injection" which allows the user to inject malicious code to your SQL server via an input box.

You have a `SELECT * FROM` in your initial code. Its better to spell out the columns you want to display.I would also probably ask for `where appointmentdate = getdate()` in my SQL Stored Procedure or if you insisted on inline SQL because it cant be injected: `selectcommand = "SELECT fieldname from appointments where appointmentdate =" & "'" & now.date.tostring() & "'"`

**Logic for how to search for appointment and check in**

Say you are on the default.aspx page and the user types in their name and ssn. You will call the stored procedure from the code which passes, firstname, lastname and ssn. If it returns one row exactly then `response.redirect("checkIn.aspx?id=" & returnedIdFromSproc)`

On that page you have it display the question "Would you like to check in" with two buttons. Yes or No. Behind Yes you call the sproc to check in passing the ID, with a no you  `response.redirect("default.aspx")`

If check in is successful you use the returnedIdFromSproc and pass it into another sproc which will make the update as checkedIn.

Does that help?

Comment: The reasoning behind the "select * from" was simply to test the sql connection to make sure the asp page was reading from the database (debugging) and will be removed or commented out of the final product. Where does the code go to do SQL Injection? global.asax?

Comment: I figured so but I wanted to point out that sure for a small number of people it probably wont make a difference but at some point the "appointments" table will become very large and fixing it then could become problematic.

Comment: oops, I mean stored procedure

Comment: "Where does the code go to do SQL Injection? global.asax?" Huh?

Comment: SQL injection is a form of hacking that allows the user to put in malicious code in your text box to pass commands to SQL

Comment: Here is a link to show you how to add a parameter to a command object : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx